# C++ and SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, c++, zip, compression

I'm not that well versed when it comes to compression algorithms.

I have a piece of C# code that uses aforementioned library to compres and uncompress a chunk of data. It uses compression level 3, but other than that, it's the most basic implementation.

I now want to do the same with that data using c++. Since it's a zip format, we are talking about the deflate algorithm, right?

Am I correct to assume that any c++ library that deals with zip compression uses that algorithm and that it's compatible with C# version? Is the level 3 compression a zip standard, or something unique to C# lib?

Basically, what do I have to look out for, if anything, when looking for and implementing the library into my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since it's a zip format, we are talking about the deflate algorithm, right?

Not all .zip files use the DEFLATE algorithm. The ZIP specification lists a large number of different compression methods it supports:

```
4.4.5 compression method: (2 bytes)

    0 - The file is stored (no compression)
    1 - The file is Shrunk
    2 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 1
    3 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 2
    4 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 3
    5 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 4
    6 - The file is Imploded
    7 - Reserved for Tokenizing compression algorithm
    8 - The file is Deflated
    9 - Enhanced Deflating using Deflate64(tm)
   10 - PKWARE Data Compression Library Imploding (old IBM TERSE)
   11 - Reserved by PKWARE
   12 - File is compressed using BZIP2 algorithm
   13 - Reserved by PKWARE
   14 - LZMA (EFS)
   15 - Reserved by PKWARE
   16 - Reserved by PKWARE
   17 - Reserved by PKWARE
   18 - File is compressed using IBM TERSE (new)
   19 - IBM LZ77 z Architecture (PFS)
   97 - WavPack compressed data
   98 - PPMd version I, Rev 1
```

> Am I correct to assume that any c++ library that deals with zip compression uses that algorithm and that it's compatible with C# version?

It's really up to the library authors to decide what they support, though DEFLATE *should* be implemented in almost every compression library due to its widespread use. Not all libraries are compatible with SharpZipLib though, because different programmers will have different ideas of how to best organise their code.

> Is the level 3 compression a zip standard, or something unique to C# lib?

It is part of the standard.

```
    4 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 3
```

> Basically, what do I have to look out for, if anything, when looking for and implementing the library into my code?

Make sure the library supports any compression methods you want to use, make sure the API makes sense to you, and try to find benchmarks of the library being used to see how fast it is. If you need to do stuff with the zip data other than reading and writing disk, then make sure the library can write to a stream or byte buffer for sending over a network, for example.

[Link](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) to the ZIP specification.

Answer (score 0):

The compression level is a tradeoff of speed vs. compression ratio selected at the time of compression. It has no bearing whatsoever on the ability of a decompressor to decompress it.

It is highly likely that your zip file contains deflated entries. You can use any unzipper to list the contents and find out.